# Get data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root) to refresh when UI inputs change

Tags: knockout.js

What is the best way to get this to auto update when the UI inputs bound to the view model changes.

```
<div style="word-wrap: break-word" data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root)"></div>
```

Edit_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*____**

```
 var ViewModel = (function () {
    function ViewModel(json) {
        this.Foo= ko.observableArray(json.Foo);

    }
    return ViewModel;
})();
var viewModel = new ViewModel(rawJson);
$(document).ready(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

Comment: This will auto-update if any values in `$root` are observable.  Are they in your case?

Comment: they all are observable, the text doesn't update :(

Comment: OK- you will likely need to put something in jsFiddle or show some additional code.  If you change an observable's value, then the binding that you have shown will be triggered and show the new value.

Comment: Also, be sure you call ko.applyBindings(yourviewModel) to make sure the bindings have been setup.

Comment: @RPNiemeyer sure, I've put the js in the edit..